# Access variable outside function scope

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

This is a simplified version of what I am trying to accomplish, but I want to pass a variable outside the scope of the function. I am declaring the variable outside the function but can't get it.

HTML:

```html
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var gsd = "";
    $("p").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() === "5") {
            var gsd = $(this).text();
            alert(gsd); // this works
        }
    })
    alert("get var outside func" + gsd); //does not work
});
```

Comment: Yes, I see that it is, however, Igor's answer below about "redeclaring" the variable inside the function was right to the point.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You redeclare `gsd` as a new variable inside your function. Remove `var` in front of `gsd` inside the function to address the `gsd` in the outer scope.

Comment: `gsd` isn't global...

Comment: so, the outer scope should be gsd="", instead of var gsd=""?

Comment: @user2232681 - no, the first definition of `gsd` is correct for the code shown. However, its scope is the anonymous function connected to `$(document).ready`, not global. If you want to use `gsd` in other parts of javascript in the page, then either omit `var` in front of it, or declare it in the global scope - directly inside `script` tag.