# Pass jquery var to next / other function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I try to pass a var that I get from an ajax request on focusout to the next mouseover function.

But the var that I define in the first focusout function is not accessible/undefined in the second mouseover funtion. Is there a clean simple way to do that?

[here is the jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/zfta0apa/1/)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
    var mc;

        $('#login').on('focusout', function() {
            var mc = $('#login').val();
            alert(mc)
        });

        $("#submit").on('mouseover', function() {
            alert(mc)   
        });
    });
```

and here is my original code with the ajax request

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var access_key = '123456';
    var mc;

    $('#userLoginName').on('focusout', function () {
        var email = $('#userLoginName').val()
        // verify email address via AJAX call
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://ajaxrequesturl.de/check?key=' + access_key + '&email=' + email,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (json) {

                // Access and use your preferred validation result objects
                console.log(json.format_valid);
                console.log(json.smtp_check);
                console.log(json.score);
                var mc = json.smtp_check;
                //alert(json.smtp_check);
                //alert(mc);    
            }
        });
    });

    $(".nextstep-inner").on('mouseover', function () {
        if (mc) {
            $(".isa_error").hide();
        } else {
            $(".isa_error").show();
        }
        alert(mc);
    });
});
```

Comment: You're redefining the `mc` variable in the `focusout` handler. Just remove the `var` keyword in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `$('#login').on('focusout', ...)` function you are creating a new `mc` variable local to that function, which is shadowing the other variable defined outside.

Replace:

```
    $('#login').on('focusout', function() {
        var mc = $('#login').val();
        alert(mc)
    });
```

with:

```
    $('#login').on('focusout', function() {
        mc = $('#login').val();
        alert(mc)
    });
```

Comment: This question already has an answer here:
[Access variable outside function scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942043/access-variable-outside-function-scope) 1 answer