# Ajax fetch data using outside of ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax

[i want to use value variable data from outside.How can i doing this? please help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhf0c.png)

Answer (score 0):

if i had anderstood, you can pass the variable as argument of the function but to pass an argoment to a function in a function you can do `function(firstparameterOfTheFirstFunction)(secondoparameterOFtheSeconFunction)`

Comment: var value = '';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'new2.php', //This is the current doc
            type: "POST",
            dataType:'json',
          //  async: false,// add json datatype to get json
            data: ({id: 2}),
            success: function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
                 value = data[1];
i want to use the data of this variable called "value" form outside of ajax scope without pass any parameter or function.is it possible?

Comment: try reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942043/access-variable-outside-function-scope