# How to get window.width() value outside of $(window).resize function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a solution to get the width of window outside the `$(window).resize` function. I am working on a slider and want to make changes to its `slidesToShow` property.

I want the width value in the `$jq('.autoplay').slick` function to change the value of `slidesToShow`. If the width is less than `1000` slidesToShow value must be `2` etc.

I have taken help from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942043/access-variable-outside-function-scope) but it's not working for me.

```js
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
$jq(document).on('ready', function() {
  $jq(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $jq(window).width();
  });

  $jq('.autoplay').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    prevArrow: '<div class="slick-prev"><i class="lni-chevron-left"></i></div>',
    nextArrow: '<div class="slick-next"><i class="lni-chevron-right"></i></div>'
  });
});
```

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you can just use the `responsive` property in the options object you pass to `.slick`. See here (scroll down to "responsive display"): http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: thanks bro, its my mistake it didn't checked that responsive area of slick, let me try that too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you need in a better way without having to worry about variable scope. You can do this by calculating the `slidesToShow` value within the `resize` event handler and then update the existing Slick slider instance's `slidesToShow` property within that block. Something like this:

```js
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

$jq(document).on('ready', function() {
  $jq(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $jq(window).width();
    var slidesToShow = /* calculate value based on width here... */ ;
    $slick.slick('slickSetOption', 'slidesToShow', slidesToShow);
  });

  var $slick = $jq('.autoplay').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    prevArrow: '<div class="slick-prev"><i class="lni-chevron-left"></i></div>',
    nextArrow: '<div class="slick-next"><i class="lni-chevron-right"></i></div>'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your variable on the upper function so it's accessible in all the inner functions, like this :

```
    var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    $jq(document).on('ready', function() {
        // if you declare a variable here;
        var myVar = 0;
        $jq( window ).resize(function() { 
            var width = $jq( window ).width();
            // then initialize it here;
            myVar = $jq( window ).width();
        });
        $jq('.autoplay').slick({
            slidesToShow: myVar > 30 ? 'yes': 'no', // you can use it here, since it is in the scope
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 2000,
            prevArrow: '<div class="slick-prev"><i class="lni-chevron-left"></i></div>',
            nextArrow: '<div class="slick-next"><i class="lni-chevron-right"></i></div>'
        });
    });
```

Comment: This won't work. myVar is only updated on resize. This does not have any effect on slick.